# Where is the list of recent files stored?

Tags: backup, synchronization, sublimetext2

I would like to syncronize certain Sublime Tex2 settings between multiple computers.  One thing I don't want to sync is the Recent File list. Where on the local file system does Sublime Text 2 store its list of recently opened files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X this list is stored in a file called `Session.sublime_session` under `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings`, so I'd expect it to be in the same file in Sublime's Settings folder on other operating systems as well.

Comment: On Windows: `AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Settings`.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux it is stored in the file `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings/Session.sublime_session`, so look for such a file in the Settings folder in your user directory.