# Getting the Sublime Text recently closed file list with the API

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

Is there any way to get the list of recently closed files using the Sublime Text API?

The SO [Where is the list of recent files stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225256/where-is-the-list-of-recent-files-stored) question says they are stored in the `Session.sublime_session` config file, although I think that file is only updated when ST closes and files closed during the current session are in `Auto Save Session.sublime_session`.

However the `.sublime_session` files can not be loaded using the API's `load_settings(base_name)` method. I am not at all sure it would be *safe* to open a `.sublime_session` file directly.

You can open the most recently closed files using the following command (indexed from 0)...

```
sublime.active_window().run_command('open_recent_file', {"index": 0})
```

...but is there a way of getting a list of the recently closed files instead (with the API)?

If not, would it be safe to open `Auto Save Session.sublime_session` for reading?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it should be safe to open `Auto Save Session.sublime_session` for reading. The other possibility that comes to mind would be to track when files are closed, and maintain your own list of recently closed files. Maybe this plugin does something similar: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GotoRecent

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @KeithHall thanks for the suggestion, I already knew about that package but was hoping for an easier solution. That approach would seem to be the only reliable way forward.

Comment: @MattDMo I spent a couple of hours doing that last night, but only had time to write it up this afternoon. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as far as I can tell, it is safe to open `Auto Save Session.sublime_session` for reading.

`Auto Save Session.sublime_session` is the file which has the 'live' data in it for ST v3; it looks like ST v2 just uses `Session.sublime_session` and does not use an auto save equivalent.

The list of recently closed files is stored in the JSON using the `file_history` key. However it is more complex than I had realized. Recently closed file lists are held for each individual window, this can be seen easily if there are multiple ST windows open, `Open Recent` in the file menu will show you which files have been recently closed in that window only.

The recently closed file lists (note: plural) can be retrieved using something like the following:

```py
win_index = 0
auto_save_session_path = "/path/to/Auto Save Session.sublime_session"
with open(auto_save_session_path) as session_data_file:
    session_data = json.load(session_data_file)
    recently_closed_files = session_data["windows"][win_index]["file_history"]
```

Clearly that retrieves just the first window's `file_history`, to get them all it would be necessary to loop through the list of window entries held in the `windows` key.

So which window in the JSON corresponds to the active ST window?

Unfortunately this turns out to be more tricky than I'd hoped. Each entry in the `windows` key list has a helpful sounding `window_id`, e.g. `"window_id": 425`, but its value does NOT correspond to the integer returned by the API's `sublime.active_window().id()` method. The JSON `"window_id": 425` entry in my file corresponded to window `id()` number 3. Clearly ST holds (at least) two different IDs for each window, one for the `.sublime_session` files and one for the Python API.

The only way I can see to ID the active window is by using the window's currently open buffers. Each entry in the JSON `windows` key list has a `buffers` list which holds the currently open files in the window, these could be compared to the files open in the active window (which could be retrieved using the API) to determine which window entry in the JSON file contains the recently closed file list of the active ST window.

This method would have some theoretical pitfalls. For example it wouldn't work if there were 2 windows open with no open files in them or if a single file (the same one) was open in 2 windows. Of course in real world usage this wouldn't generally happen; multiple windows are opened by users so that they can have different files in them.

It turns out that there is a another problem; the frequency with which `Auto Save Session.sublime_session` is updated. I don't think there is a static fixed time interval. Saving a file triggers an immediate update, but opening and closing files and windows do not, and often there is a gap of at least several minutes between updates.

This means that a plugin that uses the recently closed file list from a `.sublime_session` file can not even guarantee to contain the most recently closed file.

Keith's suggestion to monitor file closures and maintain an independent list of recently closed files, as done by [GotoRecent](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GotoRecent), would seem to be the way forward, until such time as the ST API adds the ability to get the recently closed files lists.

I hope this helps anyone looking into this issue or who wants to use a `.sublime_session` file for some other data.

Comment: Another package worth checking out is https://packagecontrol.io/packages/File%20History, which is ST3-compatible and probably uses the same mechanics (listening to events). I am a co-author of that package.